# Android Regular Expression - Replace all spaces '(' ')' '-'

Tags: android, regex

I newt o regular expressions and been using tutorials, but the regular express I have works sometimes, but doesn't all the time. I am getting my numbers out of the contact list from my android phone. I am trying to get rid of all spaces, '(', ')', and '-'

For example:

```
1. (555) 867-5309 -> 5558675309
2. 1555-555-5555 -> 15555555555
3. 555-555-5555 -> 5555555555
```

This is the line I am using

```
String formatphone = contactPhone.replaceAll("\\s()-","");
```

For some numbers it only returns number and sometimes it doesn't change the format.

Is it correct? Do i need to format something because I am taking it out of the phone's contact list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the desired characters in a character class:

```
String formatphone = contactPhone.replaceAll("[ ()-]","");
```

Ensure that you put the hyphen `-` at either end.

Comment: so what is the difference between putting all the characters into a character class and the way i did it?

Comment: @user2252502 The way you did it made it a single _string_ to be replaced.  This way you tell that substitute any character within the class with the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
String formatphone = contactPhone.replaceAll("^.*[\\s\\(\\)-].*", "");
```

As a regular expression you're defining a set using `[]`. In that set you include any character you want to be replaced. As `(` and `)` are special meaning characters, you have to escape them. As the `-` is a special character used to design ranges, it has to be the last character of your set, so if nothing is behind it, it's not a range, but just that character (you could escape it too, though).